# Using MAMP and Laravel. Site shows up fine on port 8888 from MAMP, but fails on port 8000 from Laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, mamp

I get the following errors when visiting localhost:8000 . The site works fine when I got to localhost:8888.  I had the site up on a windows PC previously and it worked, I moved it over to a Mac and since haven't gotten it working.  I am using a postgres db as well, the DB works fine on port 8888.

```html
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
PDOException in Connector.php line 50:
could not find driver
in Connector.php line 50
at PDO->__construct('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=lewp', 'lewp_admin', '*****', array('0', '2', '0', false)) in Connector.php line 50
at Connector->createConnection('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=lewp', array('driver' => 'pgsql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'lewp', 'username' => 'lewp_admin', 'password' => '*****', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'prefix' => '', 'schema' => 'public', 'name' => 'pgsql'), array('0', '2', '0', false)) in PostgresConnector.php line 36
at PostgresConnector->connect(array('driver' => 'pgsql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'lewp', 'username' => 'lewp_admin', 'password' => '*****', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'prefix' => '', 'schema' => 'public', 'name' => 'pgsql')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 60
at ConnectionFactory->createSingleConnection(array('driver' => 'pgsql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'lewp', 'username' => 'lewp_admin', 'password' => '******', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'prefix' => '', 'schema' => 'public', 'name' => 'pgsql')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 49
at ConnectionFactory->make(array('driver' => 'pgsql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'lewp', 'username' => 'lewp_admin', 'password' => '*****', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'prefix' => '', 'schema' => 'public'), 'pgsql') in DatabaseManager.php line 175
at DatabaseManager->makeConnection('pgsql') in DatabaseManager.php line 67
at DatabaseManager->connection(null) in Model.php line 3175
at Model::resolveConnection(null) in Model.php line 3141
at Model->getConnection() in Model.php line 1895
at Model->newBaseQueryBuilder() in Model.php line 1838
at Model->newQueryWithoutScopes() in Model.php line 1812
at Model->newQuery() in Model.php line 3387
at Model->__call('where', array('name', '=', 'cats'))
at Lewp->where('name', '=', 'cats')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Lewp), 'where'), array('name', '=', 'cats')) in Model.php line 3403
at Model::__callStatic('where', array('name', '=', 'cats')) in FrontendController.php line 35
at Lewp::where('name', '=', 'cats') in FrontendController.php line 35
at FrontendController->index(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(FrontendController), 'index'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 256
at Controller->callAction('index', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 164
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(FrontendController), object(Route), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 112
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 114
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(FrontendController), object(Route), object(Request), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 69
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\FrontendController', 'index') in Route.php line 201
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 704
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 706
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 671
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 631
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 54
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('/Users/jahughes/Sites/lewp/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel but on the face of it, it looks like PHP is missing the PDO_PGSQL plugn. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php 
It could be that PHP for Laravel is not configured correctly or does not have access to the plugin.  Have you tried using `phpinfo();` to check the plugins you have installed? http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: @couling which would make sense, but if I visit the site via the localhost:8888 then it sees the pdo_pgsql plugin fine and works.  Also if I visit the php_info() it says it is there.

Comment: I'll be the first to admit I'm offering advice from a point of ignorance. Is the port 8888 purely changing the webserver port or is it a different webserver? I ask because each webserver typically has its own `php.ini` file and consequently different plugins. Have you checked `php_info()` from both 8888 and 8000?

Comment: @couling Okay I think I am getting closer.  pgsql doesn't show up in 8000 for laravel but shows up in 8888 for MAMP. How do I make it show up for laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Try launching with port 8000 from Terminal.
**cd** or navigate to the directory that has the laravel app.
And run the command **php -S localhost:8000 -t public**